# XSL FO failing XSLT translation in JBOSS AS 7

Tags: java, xslt, jboss7.x, xsl-fo

I have the following code

```
SAXTransformerFactory stfactory;
stfactory = (SAXTransformerFactory) TransformerFactory.newInstance();

/// ClassLoaderUriResolver is another class.
 stfactory.setURIResolver(new ClassLoaderUriResolver()); 

 InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("xsl/Hello.xsl");
 StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(is);

  mergeHandler = stfactory.newTransformerHandler(streamSource);

 XMLReader xmlReader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
```

and some more code.....

The problem is in the the line 
      ***mergeHandler = stfactory.newTransformerHandler(streamSource);***

When I run this program as a standalone JAVA program in JBOSS IDE with same set of jars

- xalan-2.7.0.jar
- xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar
- xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
- xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar

I see that the call stfactory.newTransformerHandler(streamSource);

returns
**org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerHandlerImpl**

**and MY XLST translation works fine as a simple java program**

Where as the same code when it is running on Jboss AS 7 container 
I see that the call stfactory.newTransformerHandler(streamSource);

returns
**org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl** (Not TransformerHandlerImpl)

As a result when I run on Jboss AS 7 Container as part of Web applicataion the XSLT translation is not happening and I dont see any errors. My XLS FO document is not translated.

How do I force the code to use **org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerHandlerImpl** ?

Comment: i would guess a java question. what is the classpath at execution time for both?

Comment: Based on that answer, I assume you do not understand what you are doing. That question is simple and anyone who knows Java would know the answer. Try again ... I asked "what is the classpath for each of the two" I did NOT ask what version of Java you are using.

Comment: Kevin,
Sorry here is the classpath.
Here is the complete list of jars in my class path.
version.JAXP=1.1 or higher
java.ext.dirs=C:\JAVA\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext
version.xerces2=Xerces-J 2.7.1
version.xerces1=not-present
version.xalan2_2=Xalan Java 2.7.0
java.version=1.7.0_25
version.DOM=2.0
version.SAX=2.0
version.xalan2x=Xalan Java 2.7.0
java.class.path=C:\lib\xalan-2.7.0.jar;C:\lib\batik-util-1.7.jar;C:\lib\avalon-framework-impl-4.3.1.jar;
C:\lib\fop-0.95.jar;C:\lib\xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar;C:\lib\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;C:\lib\xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
C:\lib\xmlgraphics-commons-1.3.1.jar

Comment: Kevin,
Thanks. I digged more towards class path and I got it working. Please see the answer below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working.

In jboss in addition to modules which we can exclude there is another jar that’s at the root C:\jboss-eap-6.0\jboss-modules.jar.  Inside this jar there is folder called   “__redirected” with a class __TransformerFactory.class with following code.

```
Class clazz = __RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(id, javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory, loader);
```

This forces the “org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl” to be loaded from C:\jboss-eap-6.0/jboss-modules.jar

However this is not a module so I can’t exclude it using jboss-deployment-structure.xml, though I had exclude the following jboss modules for Xalan, Xercel and XML api . As we have a specific jars in the EAR lib to satisfy this.

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns:p="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <deployment>
                            <exclusions>
                                          <module name="org.apache.xerces" />
                                            <module name="org.apache.xalan" />
                                            <module name="org.apache.xml-resolver" />
                            </exclusions>

            </deployment>
```

So I commented the following code

```
  stfactory = (SAXTransformerFactory) TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

and added

```
  Class clazz = Class.forName("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl");
  stfactory = (SAXTransformerFactory) clazz.newInstance();
```

Now I see that

- org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl is getting loaded from C:/jboss-eap-6.0/standalone/deployments/TST.ear/lib/xalan-2.7.0.jar
- The call stfactory.newTransformerHandler(streamSource) returns “org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerHandlerImpl”  and not “org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl”

So I believe that the jar “C:\jboss-eap-6.0\jboss-modules.jar” is part of class loader and above the EAR class loader. So it was not using Xalan.2.7.0.jar  for “org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl”.  However when we call  stfactory.newTransformerHandler(streamSource)   it would return “org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl” 
.

May be there is something buried in  C:\jboss-eap-6.0\jboss-modules.jar for this behavior.

What I don’t understand was in one of tests I did  use Xalan.2.7.0.jar and added that in java.endorsed.dir it was still using C:\jboss-eap-6.0\jboss-modules.jar which is little surprising as I thought the jars in endorsed will be loaded even before  C:\jboss-eap-6.0\jboss-modules.jar.

But anyway the current fix resolves the problem and it happens only on Jboss application server 7. The code works without any changes in Webspshere 7.0 and also when I run it as standalone java program.